# apache SetEnvIf Request_URI getting not working

Tags: regex, linux, apache, security

Currently running site on apache server on ubuntu and now whole site is protected with .htaccess authentication.

Want to do: I need to allow two URL without authentication.

sites1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(tools|manager)/
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /srv/site1/symfony/>
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Area"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/passwords.htpwd"
Require user user1

SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/en/App/uploadImagesForm allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
</Directory>
```

URL: xxx.xxxx.xx:9005/en/App/uploadImagesForm/

Problem Still asking password

Answer (score 0):

You can disable authentication for the whole directory

```
  <Directory "/srv/site1/symfony/public">
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

To allow only specific URI add the following code to your VirtualHost configuration.

```
<Location "/en/App/uploadImagesForm">
    AuthType None
    Require all granted
</Location>
```

Take a look at the Apache Sections Configuration documentation for more details: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#file-and-web

Comment: I tried above but still asking password; Actually followed many links but not work anynow,plz help....

Comment: @rgg The directives `AuthType None` and `Require all granted` must disable authentication. The problem must be somewhere else. Try to create a `.htaccess` file in `en/App/uploadImagesForm/` directory with 2 lines: `AuthType None` and `Require all granted`

Comment: How to allow particular URL because In this URL having  many internal link to access pages like css,js and etc. If I allow public folder then also try to get css and js so that may be asking password.

Comment: @rgg I added an example. It must be noticed that `Location` and `LocationMatch` are not allowed in `.htaccess`, but only in main apache's config

Comment: site running on /srv/site1/symfony and URL call twig file on /srv/site1/app folder and this twig file also call on symfony folder...!!!